# How do I replace an attribute in a function with a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
.load($(this).attr('href'), function (responseText, textStatus) {
```

Now, I want to modify that to loading a predefined variable instead of the `href` attribute. I tried this here but get an error:

```
params="option=1"; // example
var URL=ajax_url+"/?"+params;

.load($(this)URL, function (responseText, textStatus) {
```

What's the correct way?

Comment: Well,the `href` attribute is an URL used for the ajax call, you want a valid URL with a valid querystring, and it should work, assuming you do `.load(URL, function() {...` -> [**learn about variables**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your "URL" is valid, then it should just be:

```
.load(URL, function (responseText, textStatus) {

}
```